# How to get 2 different floats from single textbox passed inside an equation later on. (C#)

Tags: c#, windows

First of all, Hey everyone and sorry for being a dummy!

I am relatively fresh to C#, I got `getFirstNumber` and `getSecondNumber` methods, yet I can't figure out how to get `buttonEquals_Click` to work as intended.

The Idea is that:

1. User types in a number into textbox.
2. User clicks on a "+,-,*,/," button, number gets parsed to float first number.
3. User types in another number into the same textbox.
4. User clicks "=" button, number gets parsed to float second number....
   .... and he receives output of the equation in a label.

I am stuck at the last point, I can't figure it out in C#, please help me out :D

```
    public void getfirstNumber(float firstNumber,int Operation)
    {
        float firstnumber = firstNumber;
        int  operation = Operation;
    }

    public void getsecondNumber(float secondNumber)
    {
         float secondnumber = secondNumber;
    }

    private void buttonMULTIPLY_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float firstNumber = float.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);
        int multiply = 4;
        getfirstNumber(firstNumber,mul);
    }

    private void buttonEQUALS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float secondNumber = float.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);
        getsecondNumber(secondNumber);

         /* if operation == 4 
            {print in label the output of firstnumber / secondnumber
          } */
    }
```

Comment: I think you are trying to create a calculator, but I actually didn't get what `getfirstNumber` and `getsecondNumber` methods do?

Comment: You have to make "firstNumber" and "secondNumber" global properties. The way you use them now, initializes them as new every time. Read about global properties online

Comment: ...learn about `scope` - *where* you declare a variable determines where it "lives" or where you can use it.

Comment: So in the same textbox you have both numbers to be multiplied together. You need to split the content of the textbox at the first space and then you have two substrings that you can parse and multiply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `getfirstNumber()` and `getSecondNumber()` methods:

```
string Operation = "";
float firstNumber = 0, seconNumber = 0;

 private void buttonMULTIPLY_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     firstNumber = float.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);
     Operation = "*";
}

 private void buttonEQUALS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     secondNumber = float.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);
     switch(Operation)
     {
          case "*":
              textBoxInput.Text = (firstNumber * secondNumber).ToString();
              break;
          case "-":
              textBoxInput.Text = (firstNumber - secondNumber).ToString();
              break;
          case "+":
              textBoxInput.Text = (firstNumber + secondNumber).ToString();
              break;
          case "/":
              textBoxInput.Text = (firstNumber / secondNumber).ToString();
              break;

     }
    Operation = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't pass neither the first number value nor operation sign to the  buttonEQUALS method.

Comment: When multiply button is pressed `firstNumber` is set and you also set the type of operation. when `buttonEQUALS` is pressed, the `secondNumber` is set, and you now have both numbers and Operator, so can calculate the result in this button and show the result.

Comment: isn't it what you want to do? and note that click event of a button only accepts 2 parameters (object and eventargs) and you can not pass any other arguments to it.

Comment: Turned out i didn't set the events for the buttons properly, everything works fine now, thanks for your help and patience :)